# How to avoid string members in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-criteria

Is it possible to avoid using string literials in Hibernate, such as in criteria restrictions and projections:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
                   .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "john doe"));
```

or

`Projection p1 = Projection.property("name");`

For example, in the code snippets above, replacing `"name"` with `something.name`
, where `something` contains all the members of the Employee class.

It would make it less error prone, e.g. typo in the string.

EDIT: Updating question to be more general and not specific to just Criteria.

Comment: Did you try to replace `"name"` by a `"something.name"`? If yes, did you receive a error or what ?

Comment: But my problem is that I don't know what `something` should be?.

Comment: Please check my answer, it should help you.

Comment: Take a look at Yuri [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36648488/1700321) and [jooq](http://www.jooq.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Employee Constants class:

```
public class EmployeeConstants {
        public static final String firstName= "firstname";
        public static final String lastName= "lastname";
        ....
}
```

And call the field as :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
                   .add(Restrictions.eq(EmployeeConstants.firstName, "john doe"));
```

In fact `EmployeeConstants.firstName`returns `firstname` which must be the field name of the `Employee` Entity.

Comment: I have considered that but it is more of a workaround than a solution. It is certainly better than using a string literal in the Hibernate code but not as elegent as the linq syntax for example because it has additional overhead of updating the Contants class when changes to the base are made. It seems the best approach though if this isn't supported natively by Hibernate.

Comment: @JohnSteed : Yes as you say it is better than using a string literal in the hibernate code, it seems that we don't have a better solution.

Comment: But there is a better solution, more than one actually.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn on JPA's Metamodel generation and use generated classes' fields as type and name -safe "literals" with Criteria API.
Example from [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html)

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Item> items;
    BigDecimal totalCost;
    // standard setter/getter methods
}

@StaticMetamodel(Order.class) // <<<<<<<<<< this class gets generated for you
public class Order_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, Customer> customer;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Order, Item> items;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Order, BigDecimal> totalCost;
}
// type-safe and typo-proof building of query:
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
SetJoin<Order, Item> itemNode = cq.from(Order.class).join(Order_.items);
cq.where( cb.equal(itemNode.get(Item_.id), 5 ) ).distinct(true);
```

It's very handy in case of big entities and complex queries. The only downside is that sometimes it becomes very verbose to use.
And it's JPA standard, so EclipseLink and other JPA providers support it as well.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can use a query by example:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("john doe");
Example employeeExample = Example.create(employee);

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).add(employeeExample);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I was too specific in my question. I mean avoid strings throughout the usage of Hibrenate to specify member. I have updated my original question