# Does Hibernate allow writing of String/Type Safe SQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, redhat

Does Hibernate allow the writing of String/Type SQL , similar to Entity Framework /w Linq, where a person can write proper Sql,  and any misspelled SQL Table, Column names will be shown at compile time instead of run execution time?

```
create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, count())
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .join(BOOK).on(AUTHOR.ID.equal(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID))
      .where(BOOK.LANGUAGE.eq("DE"))
      .and(BOOK.PUBLISHED.gt(date("2008-01-01")))
      .groupBy(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
      .having(count().gt(5))
      .orderBy(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME.asc().nullsFirst())
      .limit(2)
      .offset(1)
```

Comment: Id depends on how you are creating your query, If you are using JPA/Native queries, no, if you are using criteria, then yes. And I can even be wrong here so much time using spring boot data that maybe something new came up for hibernate :)

Comment: hi @JorgeCampos I don't think Hibernate Criteria does string/type safe sql looking at the resources, a person can type in any string https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-queries-tutorial/

Comment: I was referring to the usage of the Criteria object using only the entity fields like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36648488/460557 in that case it does validate at compile time, but you are right, if one is using all those API calls on it using strings, there is no way. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: hi @JorgeCampos feel free to write comments as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested I'm adding my comment as an answer.

Id depends on how you are creating your query, If you are using JPA/Native queries, **no**, if you are using criteria (with only entity objects), then yes.

Here is an example of using Criteria with just entity objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36648488/460557

Although if you are using Criteria APIs that you need to pass in Strings, then the answer is also no.